# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc(1)' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

The following error appeared after deploying the application to IIS, although it's NOT the first time to deploy this web application, but this is a new update to it!

> **Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc(1)' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)**

[image]

Comment: Have you changed your solution platforms e.g. from x86 -> x64 ?

Comment: No, I haven't changed anything except some code updates

Comment: I would suggest looking at you applicationhost.config as you may be two references to ASP.NET-MVC in there. Indicated by the `(1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you tried to install the ASP.NET MVC dependency twice since you have `System.Web.Mvc(1)` instead of plain `System.Web.Mvc`, so please take note of that. More than likely, that other assembly you are using is referencing the old dll, so make sure you have the right `newVersion` value under `BindingRedirect` in your `Web.config` file, as it should look something like this:

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```